# Start aggregate with second row in r

Tags: r, aggregate

I want to use the aggregate function for multiple columns and it's working out good.

The only problem is that I want it to do the computing starting with the second row of each column,  ignoring the title of each column.

This is my function:

```
agg <- aggregate(list(museNumeric$Delta_TP9, museNumeric$Delta_AF7, museNumeric$Delta_AF8, museNumeric$Delta_TP10), by = list(museNumeric$intTimestamp), median)
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Is this r? Please tag it with the r tag. Also please fix your code block formatting.

Comment: Yes it is r, thanks for your comment. I did the editing.

Comment: You will need to give sample data, otherwise we are left with speculation about what data type you have in your columns. `dput( head( museNumeric ) )` would be a good start.

Comment: Your column titles should not be in a row, they should be in the `names` of the data frame. Please do share the `dput()` results so we can see what's going on with your data structures. If `dput(head(museNumeric))` is too long, use `dput(droplevels(head(museNumeric)))`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a `data.frame` that you want to do this on, let's call it `df`. Here's a `data.table` approach:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(df)


d[2:nrow(dt), list(new_value = median(column_name)), by = list(intTimestamp)]
```

You can replace `nrow(dt)` with `.N` and `.()` instead of `list()` as shown in the below example using `mtcars`:

```
dt <- as.data.table(mtcars)
dt[2:.N, .(new_disp = mean(disp)), by = .(gear)]

   gear new_disp
1:    4      225
2:    3      225
3:    5      225
```

You can apply multiple functions to multiple columns (they don't have to be all `mean` and aggregate by multiple columns (order matters):

```
> dt[2:.N, list(new_disp = mean(disp), median_carb = median(carb)), by = list(gear, cyl)]
   gear cyl new_disp median_carb
1:    4   6      225           2
2:    4   4      225           2
3:    3   6      225           2
4:    3   8      225           2
5:    3   4      225           2
6:    5   4      225           2
7:    5   8      225           2
8:    5   6      225           2
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before you need the column titles to be names.
Furthermore, you should use a dataframe (common structure in R).

```
# this is a data.frame
df <- data.frame(
    a = 1:10
    , b = 11:20
    , c = 21:30
)
```

I think the easiest way to go for a beginner is the "tidyverse" which contains several packages:

```
library(tidyverse)
```

Here you can do...

```
df %>%
    summarise_all(median)
```

...which translates to

```
take the dataframe (df) then (%>%)
    apply a function (median) to all columns (summarise_all)
```